# Query a kNN with out of the original cluster pictures

Tags: python, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I'm trying to use the code from a [public repository](https://github.com/ankonzoid/artificio/tree/master/similar_images_TL) to train an kNN model with a set of images. It originally works processing the similarity of all the images between the cluster. But I'd like to use a new image (not included in the model) and get the most similar images from the original cluster.

This is the code to train the original kNN

```
for f in os.listdir(path):

    # Process filename
    filename = os.path.splitext(f)  # filename in directory
    filename_full = os.path.join(path,f)  # full path filename
    head, ext = filename[0], filename[1]
    if ext.lower() not in [".jpg", ".jpeg"]:
        continue

    # Read image file
    img = image.load_img(filename_full, target_size=(224, 224))  # 
    load
    imgs.append(np.array(img))  # image
    filename_heads.append(head)  # filename head

    # Pre-process for model input
    img = process_image(img)
    features = model.predict(img).flatten()  # features
    eX.append(features)  # append feature extractor

filename_heads.append(head)

X = np.array(eX)  # feature vectors
imgs = np.array(imgs)  # images

n_neighbours = 5 + 1 
knn = kNN()  # kNN model
knn.compile(n_neighbors=n_neighbours, algorithm="brute", metric="cosine")
knn.fit(X)
```

This is my code to query a new image and find similar ones in the original cluster

```
#previously I read the image from an url and put it in img variable
img = image.load_img('db/temp.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))  # load 
img = image.img_to_array(img)  # convert to array
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = preprocess_input(img)
img_features = model.predict(img).flatten()  # features
distances, indices = knn.predict(img_features)
```

The problem is that I get a "IndexError: tuple index out of range
" error when I run knn.predict(new_img_features). I've already looked at the shape and type of the img_features and they're all the same, so I don't really know why this error appears. Maybe the error is because the kNN used here is not a classifier, but I don't know how to adapt it in order to work.

[Full code link](https://pastebin.com/vZbCDUVh) just in case you want to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had to pass the matrix this way:

```
distances, indices = knn.predict(np.array([img_features]))
```